# Malware edits index.php, wp-settings.php and config.php files everyday, edits and add a php code of different files and changes permission to w-w-w

Tags: php, wordpress

I work on WordPress CMS and have been facing issues for many months, and I have to manually edit and remove the issues on an everyday basis. The issue comes every day and I have to edit the codes everyday. The issues m facing are

1. The index, settings and config files are edited and the permission is set to w-w-w, I have taken the backups of all three files, and on every day I have to delete these effected files and upload the real once.
2. Random files get edited and a malware PHP code is added on the top of the file and same time it also changes the permission of the file to w-w-w. I have to edit them and remove those codes manually.
3. .ICO files are uploaded in different random folders and the permission is again set to w-w-w.

I get to know this by a log file sent by the server team on every day.

Please let me know if there is a way to sort this permanently.

Comment: You have to find where the issue is coming from... Firstly install Wordfence plugin, and scan for code injections...

Answer (score 0):

- The first step is to install [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) plugin and run the scan.
- It will show you the files that don't belong to Wordpress and you should basically remove all those, unless there are some custom modifications done to Wordpress itself.
- Then, you need to check the files that were altered and do belong to original Wordpress installation, possibly restoring them to the original state, otherwise manually resolving the conflicts.
- Check file permissions and set to them to the default Wordpress ones

The process of changing your files is usually automated so if you kill the source, it will stop doing it.
If after a while you don't notice any changes to your files, you should update Wordpress to the latest version along with all plugins to prevent further attacks on your website.

Disclaimer, the list of actions is not complete, but gives a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I have been doing the same, have wordfence plugin, it shows some effected files, these are not actually the default WordPress files, but these are some new uploaded files with malicious code, I have already deleted them, but still nothing is sorted, even after deleting them, the same process is repeating again and again, still unable to find the source. Password already changed for every login.